# Hortonworks Hive and SpagoBI

Tags: hive, spagobi

I want to connect hortonworks hive with SpagoBI studio i am using jdbc driver to make the connection but its not working please anyone solve this problem.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should create an environment file for the spagobi. In that file you need to provide the paths for jars of hive lib and hadoop-core.jar(for hadoop version 1)

Then you need to execute the run the env file and after that start SpagoBI.
It would run properly.

Basically this env file provides the access of jars of hive lib (including your hive-jdbc-*.jar) to SpagoBi

The environment file is

```
HADOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop
HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive

echo -e '1\x01foo' > /tmp/spagobi/a.txt
echo -e '2\x01bar' >> /tmp/spagobi/a.txt


CLASSPATH=.:$HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-core.jar:$HIVE_HOME/conf

for i in ${HIVE_HOME}/lib/*.jar ; do
    CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$i
done
`
```

just  save the code in file

> spagobi.env

and then execute the file thorugh `. spagobi-env.env`

Answer (score 0):

If you using updated version of hive then download some jar files that given below:-
1. hadoop-common-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar
2. z-hive-jdbc-0.14.0.2.2.0.0-2041-standalone.jar

then,In SpagoBI Studio -> Go to data source connection -> select hive driver -> then add new driver file "z-hive-jdbc-0.14.0.2.2.0.0-2041-standalone.jar" file -> then ok.

Then, provide credentials to connect with hive given below:-

URL : jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/xyz

Driver: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

definately, this will work.

Thanks
Aman

Answer (score -1):

Edit `server.xml`
Path: `All-In-One-SpagoBI-X.X.X\conf\server.xml`

Add:

```
<!-- Hive Configuration-->
<Resource name="jdbc/hive" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" 
 url="jdbc:hive2://data_node_server.com:10000/wsms" username=" " password=" "
 maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>
```

Edit `context.xml`
Path: `All-In-One-SpagoBI-X.X.X\webapp\spagobi\meta-inf\context.xml`

Add:

```
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/hive" name="jdbc/hive" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

Do same with all `context.xml` for each engine:

```
All-In-One-SpagoBI-XXX\webapps\XXXEngine\META-INF
```

Add Following Jars in `All-In-One-SpagoBI-XXX\lib`:

1. httpcore-4.3.jar
2. httpclient-4.3-beta2.jar
3. httpclient-4.2.jar
4. hadoop-common-xxx.jar
5. hive-exec.jar
6. hive-jdbc-xxx.jar
7. hive-metastore-xxx.jar
8. hive-service-xxx.jar
9. slf4j-api-xxx.jar (present in webapp/spagobi/web-inf/lib)
10. hadoop-auth-xxx.jar (optional but recommended - may be required for kerberos or other authentication)

## Data source

```
Label           :   hive2_conn  (hive-jdbc-1.2.1000.2.4.0.0-169)    
Description     :   Connecting to hive
Dialect         :   Hive QL
url             :   jdbc:hive2://server_name.com:10000/wsms (Note use data node server address , name node server wont work)
user            :   hive_user_name  
pwd             :   hvie_user_pwd                       
Driver          :   org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

Environment Variables -  Hive Server (Data Node) (set variable for user which is used in data source)

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
HADOOP_HOME=/usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/hadoop
HIVE_HOME=/usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/hive    CLASSPATH=.:$HADOOP_HOME/*.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/*.jar:$HIVE_HOME/lib/*.jar
```

Hadoop Server Configurations(`hive-site.xml`):

```
<!-- hive Multi user Support -->
<property>
  <name>hive.support.concurrency</name>
  <description>Enable Hive's Table Lock Manager Service</description>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <description>Zookeeper quorum used by Hive's Table Lock Manager</description>
  <value>zk1.myco.com,zk2.myco.com,zk3.myco.com</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>atlas.hook.hive.maxThreads</name>
    <value>50</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>atlas.hook.hive.minThreads</name>
  <value>5</value>
</property>

<!-- Configute to Support HTTP protocol default value binary (set it to http)-->
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.transport.mode</name>
  <value>http</value><!--default is binary-->
</property>

<!-- Query Optimization -->
<!-- Enable Cost Based Optimization , To Optimize Query Executio plan default value false  (set it to True) -->
<property>
  <name>hive.cbo.enable</name>enter code here
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```